# Customizable Angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript

Im kinda beginner with Angular and just wondering if this is possible to achive.

list-people.component.html

```
<my-table [dataSource]="dataSource" [pagination]="true">

  <my-column id="id" name="ID" sortable></my-column>

  <my-column id="user" name="Full Name" *row="let row"> //Maybe somehow get the row data
    {{ row.user.name }} {{ row.user.last }}
  </my-column>

  <my-column id="country" name="Country" sortable></my-column>

  <my-column id="actions" name="">
    <button (click)="edit(this)">Edit</button> //should get row data to edit click function
  </my-column>

</my-table>
```

list-people.component.ts (Short ver)

```
export class ListPeople {
  data: MatTableDataSource<?>;// ? Should be a interface

  ngOnInit() {
    const list = [
      {
        id: 1,
        country: 'England',
        user: {
          name: 'Peter',
          last: 'Gustavf'
        }
      }
    ];

    this.data = new MatTableDataSource(list);
  }
}
```

Ive tried but failed, so is this hard or should i give up on this?
I did manage to print the values for each my-column inside my-table dont know what to do to continue

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried to check any of the examples on the Angular Material Table [site](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples)

A basic example applied to your provided data could be like this

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Country </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.country}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="user">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> User </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.user.name}} {{element.user.last}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

And in your `ListPeople` component, add `displayedColumns` property

```js
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'country', 'user'];
```

Comment: Yeah i have, the reason i wanted a custom table is that i really don't want to write all those ng-containers, I just wanted to write one line for each element

Comment: Check this example, and try to to do something similar
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-generated-columns

Comment: haa, ive looked at all those examples multiple times. My code is almost working tho, i just need to figure out how to set mat-sorting-header without it to yell at me in the console. and pass let element to my-column so i can access it outside. Ima ask in Angular Discord since its kinda bad just edit my answer i think

Comment: Create a new question with the `mat-sort` issue you are facing

Comment: Yeah i should do that, i probably get downvoted again lmao. im so bad at explaining

Comment: nvm, im not allowed to ask answeres anymore

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Imagine a .html to create a mat-data-table

```
<table *ngIf="displayedColumns" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let cell of cells; let i = index"
    [matColumnDef]="displayedColumns[i]"
  >
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ titles[i]}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"></td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

You need  datasource, displayedColumns, an Array titles and **important** the "TemplateRef" of the *matCellDef

So the idea is that in your .html you has some like

```
<app-my-table [source]="items">
  <td app-cell  name="name" title="Name" *row="let data">{{ data.name }}</td>
  <td app-cell  name="id" title="Id" *row="let data">{{ data.id }}</td>
</app-my-table>
```

See that you need two Directive, the directive "row" and the directive "app-cell"

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'app-cell,td[app-cell]',
})
export class CellDirective {
  @HostBinding('class') class="mat-cell"
  @Input() name;
  @Input() title;
  constructor() {}
}

//and
@Directive({
  selector: '[row]',
})
export class RowDirective  {
  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

The app-table component like

```
export class AppTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChildren(CellDirective) cellDatas: QueryList<CellDirective>;
  @ContentChildren(RowDirective) cells: QueryList<RowDirective>;

  @ViewChildren(MatCellDef) cellDefs:QueryList<MatCellDef>
  @ViewChild(MatTable) matTable:MatTable<any>

  @Input() source

  dataSource:any[];
  displayedColumns:string[];
  templates:TemplateRef<any>[]
  titles: any[] = [];
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      //first we give value to displayedColumns
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.displayedColumns=this.cells.map((x,i)=>'col'+i)
      })

      //we subscribe to cellDefs to asign the TemplateRef
      //from our *row templates
      this.cellDefs.changes.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res=>{
        const templates=this.cells.toArray().map(x=>x.templateRef);
        res.forEach((x,i)=>{
          x.template=templates[i]
        })
        setTimeout(()=>{
          this.dataSource=this.source
        })
      })

      //we get the "titles"
      this.cellDatas.changes.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((res) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
          this.titles = res
          .map((x) => x.title)
          .reduce((a, b) => (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ? [...a, b] : a), []);
        })
      });
  }
}
```

NOTE: ther're a severals setTimeouts to avoid the error "afterchecked", if I'll get avoid, I 'll update the answer

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-acw3rc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-table%2Fapp-table.component.ts)

**Update** We can use rxjs operator delay to avoid this "ugly" setTimeOut

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.displayedColumns = this.cells.map((x, i) => 'col' + i);
    })
    this.cellDefs.changes.pipe(take(1), delay(0)).subscribe((res) => {
      const templates = this.cells.toArray().map((x) => x.templateRef);
      res.forEach((x, i) => {
        x.template = templates[i];
      });
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.source);
      if (this.withSort) this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      if (this.withPaginator) this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
    this.cellDatas.changes.pipe(take(1), delay(0)).subscribe((res) => {
      this.titles = res
        .map((x) => x.title)
        .reduce((a, b) => (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ? [...a, b] : a), []);
      this.displayedColumns = res
        .map((x) => x.name)
        .reduce((a, b) => (a.indexOf(b) < 0 ? [...a, b] : a), []);
    });
  }
```

See a [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkpiy4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-table%2Fapp-table.component.ts) with paginator and sort by defect